# MongoDB rule to delete a row if a particular column contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, triggers

I was looking for more data in delete triggers in mongodb.

Reference:

[Query on MongoDB Delete Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499863/query-on-mongodb-delete-triggers)

I want to convert DELETE to UPDATE + AUTOMATIC DELETE operation

- In my collection, I want to add one field **"flag"**.
- To delete a particular row, my application will do an UPDATE operation on the  row_to_delete and set this flag as TRUE (or 1).

My question is:

Can I define some rule in mongodb such that:

- If a particular field "flag" is set to some specific value in a row
- This row should be deleted from the collection ?

Thanks

Comment: Why does the update set a flag to delete the document, instead of just deleting the document?

Comment: @wdberkeley: to receive a trigger with complete info about the data being deleted, rather than just receiving object-id through a normal delete operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as you all ready know MongoDB doesn't have triggers in any form. You would have to call remove() with the proper query manually.